# pylint "unresolved variable from import" module level variables referenced to function

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

I have code with variables assigned to functions as shown in the example below. 
 The code works but I'm getting pylint errors when trying to use foo.x in another module.  If I define the module variable without the function reference, like variable y below I do not get a pylint error.

Any way to get pylint to recognize module1.foo.x?

```
in module1:
    def foo():
       foo.x = 1

    foo.x = 0
    y = 0

in module2:
   import module1
   p = module1.foo.x  # generates a "unresolved variable from import" for x
   p = module1.y      # no pylint errors generated for y
```

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined -> Undefined Variables From Import -> Ignore

Then try to close and reopen eclipse again.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think PyLint doesn't seem to be recognizing that pattern (adding variables to a method)... you can try reporting an issue to them to see if they're open to fixing it (https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues).

So, a workaround would be disabling that check in that line (inside PyDev you can do `Ctrl+1` in that line and it'll provide an option for you to add a comment to ignore that PyLint error in that line).